# MetroStyle breadcrumb control

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-8, modern-ui

I want to create an addressbar (like the one for Windows Explorer). My app requires a breadcrumb bar.

I wanted to see if there's a breadcrumb for Metro UI in Windows 8. If not, how can I create one?

Comment: `ItemsControl`, `ItemsControl`, `ItemsControl`! Did I mention `ItemsControl`?

Comment: @HighCore :)) Awesome. Thanks for the help. Is there a chance you could give me a code snippet for this? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use these Version from CodeProject and port it to WP8 (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29350/WPF-BreadcrumbBar)

Or use these Library (http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Windows8-UI-Controls.aspx)